# Power App Clear Collection after save Custom form

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, collection

I have two `SharePoint Lists` with one `Custom Form`. Custom Form has two Screens. Each screen is connected to own `Sharepoint List`. First screen of Custom form using for save data to SharePoint list main button which is included on SharePoint.

Second screen of form is connected to second SharePoint list and using custom save button.

First of all I created a `Collection` for storing data inputs and save to second SharePoint list. Problem is I don't know how to clear `Collection` and prepare for another users inputs. Data is stored in collection from last time.

`App - onStart`

```
ClearCollect(ItemCollection, {Line1:"", Line2:0, Line3:"", Line4:""});
```

`Save button - OnSelect`

```
Patch(
ItemCollection,
ThisItem,
{
    Line1: txt1.Text,
    Line2: Value(txt1.Text),
    Line3: dd3.Selected.Value,
    Line4: dd4.Selected.Value
}
);
Collect(
    ItemCollection,
    {
        Line1: "",
        Line2: 0,
        Line3: "",
        Line4: ""
    }
);
```

because I don't know how many new lines of items user need, `save button` Patches values and creates another line for new inputs in `Gallery`.

Where to put `Clear(ItemCollection);` and not store items for new users inputs?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why are you collecting a new line/item when you want to create a collection? Did you try using `Clear(ItemCollection);` instead of Collect after Patch function?

Comment: ````Clear(ItemCollection)```` dont work. I need new line becosue one line represent is one item of invoice. If invoice has 10 items, need create 10 lines and put to collection.